# Чтение чисел из файла Java

Tags: java, переменные

В одном из классов происходит запись данных в файл "save.txt". Записываются 4 числа через пробел (например) **100 0 7 6** . Далее их нужно считать из того же файла и использовать каждый по отдельности (для форматирования и дальнейшей работы). Для форматирования они должны быть типа int. Пример кода с сохранением данных:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Save {
static int health, armor, strength, agility;

public static void save() {
    health = 100;
    armor = 0;
    strength = 7;
    agility = 6;

    try {
        File saveFile = new File("save.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(saveFile);
        pw.print(health + " " + armor + " " + strength + " " + agility);
        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну а сам вопрос в чем? Считывайте из файла строку, разбивайте через метод split в массив, приводите к типу int элементы и используйте.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте метод load()

Читайте в нем ваш файл в одну строку.

Конвертируйте строку в массив при помощи стандартной операции split() http://proglang.su/java/strings-split

Присвойте вашим параметрам  health, armor, strength, agility значения, взяв их по индексу из полученного массива.

P.S Лучше сделать так, чтобы save() принимал в аргументы параметры health, armor, strength, agility и уже их сохранял, а то у вас всегда дефолтное значение записывается.

Comment: Save и так принимает значения, просто убрал лишнее, чтобы не путать. Спасибо за подсказку))